# How to filter exact phrase in table?

Tags: javascript

Can someone please help with this code;

```
<style>
  #myInput {
  background-image: url('https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/b/R29vZ2xl/AVvXsEh8iOHV-jsRl0FQ2hVomg1GUjdg4W63HoqXrREEp4m5KNpOVWRAJRxJD_SBXN-l2hlAc7rbL_LNpl145QhEjTUC54EHfJImTH-gKe-a2CtD8XFq9ZBUG4xJekQwHfIvIP4yaU_Zm-QX3HnvawVcXY82APg5QNY6rlcKX2Bx9b3wQ6v_f7zVuOF19Mn4/s1600/149852.png'); /* Add a search icon to input */
  background-position: 10px 12px; /* Position the search icon */
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the icon image */
  width: 60%; /* Full-width */
  font-size: 16px; /* Increase font-size */
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px; /* Add some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
  margin-bottom: 12px; /* Add some space below the input */
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse; /* Collapse borders */
  width: 100%; /* Full-width */
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
  font-size: 18px; /* Increase font-size */
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left; /* Left-align text */
  padding: 12px; /* Add padding */
}
</style>

<script>
const myFunction = () => {
  const trs = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr:not(.header)')
  const filter = document.querySelector('#myInput').value
  const regex = new RegExp(filter, 'i')
  const isFoundInTds = td => regex.test(td.innerHTML)
  const isFound = childrenArr => childrenArr.some(isFoundInTds)
  const setTrStyleDisplay = ({ style, children }) => {
    style.display = isFound([
      ...children // <-- All columns
    ]) ? '' : 'none' 
  }
  
  trs.forEach(setTrStyleDisplay)
}
</script>
```

I need it to show results with the exact phrases. For instance, if I type DR it should only show where DR is alone and not part of a sentence. Unfortunately, I can't explain it any better than this, but ask me questions and I'll try to provide an answer. Not a program.

Comment: Can you create a complete snippet ? (html/js)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I've included the css and the js.

Comment: So make your regular expression match the whole string `/^foo$/` or use `td.innerHTML === filter` or toLowerCase them to get it case insensitive.

Comment: @epascarello sorry, but what would that final code look like? I'm so sorry, but I am not a coder by any means.

Answer (score 0):

Make your regular expression match start '^' and end '$' of a string.

```js
const tds = document.querySelectorAll("table tbody td");
const highlightRows = (text) => {
  var re = new RegExp('^' + text + '$', 'i');
  tds.forEach(td => {
    if (td.textContent.trim().match(re)) {
      td.classList.add("selected");
      td.closest("tr").classList.add("selected");
    }
  })
};


highlightRows("foo");
```

```css
tr.selected td{
  background-color: yellow;
}

tr.selected td.selected{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>foo bar</td>
      <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>foo</td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Here's the example of the page and code >> https://juvefcbalkan.blogspot.com/2022/10/rec-name-position-nat-club-eduardo.html

Now when you type DR in the search bar above the table, it should filter all the players that have DR position.

Comment: So `new RegExp('^' + filter + '$', 'i');` does not work?

Comment: Could you take a look at https://juvefcbalkan.blogspot.com/2022/10/rec-name-position-nat-club-eduardo.html this is the table I want to be filtered when typing.  So when you type DR in the search bar above the table, it should filter all the players that have DR position, and not include results when dr is part of a name or a club name.

Comment: It does but excludes a result where for instance I have DR / DC, I would like for it to include such a result. Don't know if that's possible.

Comment: That is NOT what you said you wanted. *"if I type DR it should only show where DR is alone and not part of a sentence."*

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I didn't know it could be so excludable. First time posting here, and I have no idea how to do this. I appreciate all the help you've given me so far. Thank you.

Is there a way to make this work, or is this a lost cause?